# Is it possible to remove the hand cursor that appears when hovering over a link? (or keep it set as the normal pointer)

Tags: css, hyperlink, mouse-cursor

I would like to remove the hand cursor that appears when you hover over a hyperlink.

I have tried this css:

```
a.link {
    cursor: pointer;
}
```

And this:

```
a.link {
    cursor: pointer !important;
}
```

And still it changes to the hand when I hover over the link.

Does anyone have any ideas as to why this happens or a solution that would enable me to achieve this effect?

Comment: so is you anchor decorated with a 'link' css class?

Comment: you need to use the [:hover](http://w3schools.com/cssref/sel_hover.asp) pseudo class

Answer (score 185, accepted):

That's exactly what `cursor: pointer;` is supposed to do.

If you want the cursor to remain normal, you should be using `cursor: default`

Comment: Thank you, solved the problem for me. I guess it was down to my interperation of pointer. Do you have any idea what kind of browser support this has? I am trying to hide a link to my back end section, so i would want this to appear in this manner always...

Comment: It has complete browser support: [you should google more](http://www.quirksmode.org/css/cursor.html)

Answer (score 17):

Using inline styling use `<a href="your link here" style="cursor:default">your content here</a>`.
See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Srz4Z/)

Alternatively use css. See this [example](http://jsfiddle.net/Srz4Z/1/).

This solution is cross-browser compatible.

Answer (score 5):

```
<button>
  <a href="https://accounts.google.com/ServiceLogin?continue=http%3A%2F%2Fmail.google.com%2Fmail%2F%3Fpc%3Den-ha-apac-in-bk-refresh14&service=mail&dsh=-3966619600017513905"
     style="cursor:default">sign in</a>
</button>
```

Answer (score 5):

Try this

**To Remove Hand Cursor**

```
a.link {
    cursor: default;
}
```

Answer (score 3):

```
<style>
a{
cursor: default;
}
</style>
```

> In the above code [**cursor:default**] is used. Default is the usual arrow cursor that appears.

And if you use [**cursor: pointer**] then you can access to the hand like cursor that appears when you hover over a link.

> **To know more** about cursors and their appearance click the below link:
> https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_cursor.asp