# How to remove cursor and hand

Tags: javascript, cursor

How could I remove cursor and hand visibility from my website. I already removed cursor but when cursor is over a link it shows up as a hand. I used this code to remove cursor: `document.body.style.cursor = "none";`

I added imgs for visualisation

[On page](https://i.stack.imgur.com/50Fp9.png)

[On link](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4d50o.png)

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Is it possible to remove the hand cursor that appears when hovering over a link? (or keep it set as the normal pointer)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8953485/is-it-possible-to-remove-the-hand-cursor-that-appears-when-hovering-over-a-link)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hey – you may need to disable the cursor on hover as well

```
a:hover {
  cursor: none;
}
```

This disables the cursor whenever you hover over an a-tag

Answer (score 0):

You could set cursor: none; on all a elements with a setting in a  in your head element..

```css
a {
  cursor: none;
}
```

```html
<a href="#">A link </a>
```